# Problemas ao recuperar dados do Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando recuperar dados do banco Mysql para um formulário, consegui recuperar alguns dados porém outros exibem - `Resource id #7/#4`

PHP:

```
@$id = $_GET['v'];   

$res=mysql_query("select * from login where cdlogin = '$id'");
$res_pes=mysql_query("select * from pessoa p inner join login l on p.cdlogin = l.cdlogin where p.cdlogin = '$id'");
$mostrar = mysql_fetch_array($res_pes);
$mostra = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$login = $mostra["LOGIN"];
$senha = $mostra["SENHA"];
$cdlogin = $mostra["CDLOGIN"];
$nome = $mostrar["NMPESSOA"];
$aux_rua = $mostrar["CDRUA"];
echo $aux_rua."<br/>";
$rua = mysql_query("select nmrua from rua where cdrua = '$aux_rua'");
echo $rua."<br/>";
echo "<script>alert('perai');</script>";
$aux_bairro = $mostrar["CDBAIRRO"];
$bairro = mysql_query("select nmbairro from bairro b inner join pessoa p on b.cdbairro = p.cdbairro where b.cdbairro = '$aux_bairro';");
$aux_cidade = $mostrar["CDCIDADE"];
$cidade = mysql_query("select nmcidade from cidade c inner join pessoa p on c.cdcidade = p.cdcidade where c.cdcidade = '$aux_bairro';");
$aux_estado = $mostrar["CDLOGIN"];
$estado = mysql_query("select nmestado from estado e inner join cidade c on c.cdestado = e.cdestado inner join pessoa p on p.cdcidade = c.cdcidade inner join login l on l.cdlogin = p.cdlogin where p.cdlogin = '$aux_estado'");
$cpf = $mostrar["CPF"];
$aux_tipo = $mostrar["CDTIPO"];
$tipo = mysql_query("select nmtipo from tipo t inner join login l on l.cdtipo = t.cdtipo inner join pessoa p on p.cdlogin = l.cdlogin where cdpessoa = '$aux_tipo'");
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="aux_editafim.php?v=<?php echo $mostra["CDLOGIN"];?>">
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="login" alt="user" class="txt radius" placeholder="Usuário" value="<?php echo $mostra["LOGIN"]?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="password" name="senha" alt="Senha" class="txt radius" placeholder="Senha" value="<?php echo $mostra["SENHA"]?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="nome" alt="Nome" class="txt radius" placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo $nome?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="rua" alt="Rua" class="txt radius" placeholder="Rua" value="<?php echo $rua?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="bairro" alt="tipo" class="txt radius" placeholder="Bairro" value="<?php echo $bairro?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="cidade" alt="Nome" class="txt radius" placeholder="Cidade" value="<?php echo $cidade?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="estado" alt="Nome" class="txt radius" placeholder='Estado' value="<?php echo $estado?>"/></input>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="cpf" alt="Nome" class="txt radius" placeholder="CPF" value="<?php echo $cpf?>"/>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" alt="Nome" class="txt radius" placeholder="Tipo" value="<?php echo $tipo?>"/></input>
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_ok" value="Alterar" class="txt-btn radius"/>                  
</label>
<label class="labels">
    <a href="lis_users.php"><input type="button" name="btn_cancelar" value="Cancelar" class="txt-btn radius"/></a>                     
</label>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está aqui, para cada `mysql_query()` é necessario um `mysql_fetch_assoc()` para extrair os valores da consulta executada(resource) pelo banco.

```
$bairro = mysql_query("select nmbairro from bairro b inner join pessoa p on b.cdbairro = p.cdbairro where b.cdbairro = '$aux_bairro';");
$aux_cidade = $mostrar["CDCIDADE"];
$cidade = mysql_query("select nmcidade from cidade c inner join pessoa p on c.cdcidade = p.cdcidade where c.cdcidade = '$aux_bairro';");
$aux_estado = $mostrar["CDLOGIN"];
$estado = mysql_query("select nmestado from estado e inner join cidade c on c.cdestado = e.cdestado inner join pessoa p on p.cdcidade = c.cdcidade inner join login l on l.cdlogin = p.cdlogin where p.cdlogin = '$aux_estado'");
$cpf = $mostrar["CPF"];
$aux_tipo = $mostrar["CDTIPO"];
$tipo = mysql_query("select nmtipo from tipo t inner join login l on l.cdtipo = t.cdtipo inner join pessoa p on p.cdlogin = l.cdlogin where cdpessoa = '$aux_tipo'");
```

Para corrigira faça os `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
$res = mysql_query("select nmbairro from bairro b inner join pessoa p on b.cdbairro = p.cdbairro where b.cdbairro = '$aux_bairro';");
$bairro = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$aux_cidade = $mostrar["CDCIDADE"];
$res = mysql_query("select nmcidade from cidade c inner join pessoa p on c.cdcidade = p.cdcidade where c.cdcidade = '$aux_bairro';");
$cidade = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$aux_estado = $mostrar["CDLOGIN"];
$res = mysql_query("select nmestado from estado e inner join cidade c on c.cdestado = e.cdestado inner join pessoa p on p.cdcidade = c.cdcidade inner join login l on l.cdlogin = p.cdlogin where p.cdlogin = '$aux_estado'");
$estado = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Comment: Deu certinho cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Uma última dúvida, tem como organizar isso utilizando uma função?